# Failed to cabal install poppler

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi

I am using ArchLinux, with ghc-7.0.3.

I have poppler-0.18.3 and pango-1.29.4 installed.

```
Configuring poppler-0.12.2...
Preprocessing library poppler-0.12.2...
gtk2hsC2hs: Errors during expansion of binding hooks:

./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:121: (column 12) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `PangoContext' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:140: (column 22) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `pango_context_get_type' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:144: (column 12) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `PangoLayout' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:163: (column 22) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `pango_layout_get_type' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:167: (column 12) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `PangoFont' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:186: (column 22) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `pango_font_get_type' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:190: (column 12) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `PangoFontFamily' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:209: (column 22) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `pango_font_family_get_type' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:213: (column 12) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `PangoFontFace' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:232: (column 22) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `pango_font_face_get_type' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:236: (column 12) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `PangoFontMap' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:255: (column 22) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `pango_font_face_get_type' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:259: (column 12) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `PangoFontset' in the header file.
./Graphics/UI/Gtk/Poppler/Types.chs:278: (column 22) [ERROR] 
  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `pango_fontset_get_type' in the header file.

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
poppler-0.12.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: @MatveyB.Aksenov Yes, pango-1.29.4

Comment: Doesn't Arch have a package for this?

Comment: @ivanm nope. pacman -Ss poppler result in `poppler` `poppler-data` `poppler-glib` `poppler-qt` `python-poppler`

Answer (score 1):

This patch solves that problem:

https://raw.github.com/gist/3662388/7635e7a10c5b75f5127c1fbc60ba5caa46d4db0c/poppler-0.12.2-patch-for-recent-gtk.patch

Comment: Broken link, presumably [this](https://gist.github.com/wavewave/3662388#file-poppler-0-12-2-patch-for-recent-gtk-patch) is the same patch.